# Database not working after publishing website on IIS - C# Web Services

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, web, iis

Hope you're doing well!

I will try to be brief,

I made a web service called "Contacts.asmx" that have this code:

```
    [WebMethod]
public DataTable GetContacts()
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    dt.TableName = "Customers";
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and and I have this code in my web.config

```
<add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Desktop\InternetApp\Folder\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Seems to be working fine and i'm getting the XML when i click invoke.

But after publishing website on IIS : http://localhost/Contacts, i'm having this problem:
[image]

What should i do?

Comment: What is the connection string?  When running locally the credentials are the user.  You are making a HTTP request from client to server and then making the query to the database from the server.  the credentials are then the credentials of the user that started the service on the server (not the client).  See Roles : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Comment: I posted as a screenshot, connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Desktop\InternetApp\Folder\database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

Comment: Integrated Security = true is using the credentials of the user that started the application not the role of the client.  that is why you need to setup a role.  The link has sample code that you can download at top of page.